# IndexError: list index out of range using classes

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
class Island (object):
    def __init__(self, i,j,k, wolf_count=0, eagle_count=0, rabbit_count=0, pigeon_count=0,):
        '''Initialize grid to all 0's, then fill with animals
        '''
        # print(n,prey_count,predator_count)
        self.i=i
        self.j=j
        self.k=k
        self.cube= []

        for k in range(k):
            self.square=[]
            for j in range(j):
                row=[0]*i
                self.square.append(row)
            self.cube.append(self.square)
        self.init_animals(wolf_count, eagle_count, rabbit_count, pigeon_count)

    def init_animals(self,wolf_count, eagle_count, rabbit_count, pigeon_count):

        count = 0
        while count < wolf_count:
            i = random.randint(0,self.i-1)
            j = random.randint(0,self.j-1)
            k = 0
            if not self.animal(i,j,k):
                new_Wolf=Wolf(island=self,i=i,j=j,k=0)
                count += 1
                self.register(new_Wolf)

    def animal(self,i,j,k):
        '''Return animal at location (i,j,k)'''
        if 0 <= i < self.i and 0 <= j < self.j and 0 <= k < self.k:
            return self.cube[i][j][k]
        else:
            return -1
```

These are sections of my program which are calling each other. When I try to run the program it gives me:

```
IndexError: list index out of range.
```

It says it for the `return self.cube[i][j][k]` in `animal()`. In reference to the  `if not self.animal(i,j,k):` section  in `init_animals()`. which is again in reference to the line `isle = Island(i,j,k, initial_Wolf, initial_Pigeon, initial_Eagle, initial_Rabbit)` in `__init__()`.

any idea why I get this error? Sorry if its hard to read.

Comment: As a side note, instead of `randint(0, foo-1)`, just do `randrange(0, foo)` or, even more simply, `randrange(foo)`.

Comment: As another side note: Using `0` for an "empty" value for a field that doesn't normally have numbers in it is very strange. Use `None` (or maybe a special instance of some base class of `Wolf`, `Eagle`, `Rabbit`, and `Pigeon`, or an instance of an `Empty` sister class) and it'll be clearer what you're up to. The `if not …` will still work fine with `None` (and, if you define a `__nonzero__`, it can work fine for your own custom objects too).

Answer (score 1):

Your outer list `self.cube` has `k` entries, each a nested list with `j` entries, each containing lists of `i` entries. Reverse your indices:

```
return self.cube[k][j][i]
```

or invert the way you are creating your `self.cube` list:

```
for _ in range(i):
    square = []
    for _ in range(j):
        square.append([0] * k)
    self.cube.append(self.square)
```

or more compact still using list comprehensions:

```
self.cube = [[[0] * k for _ in range(j)] for _ in range(i)]
```

Comment: for the quick reply. 
I just tried implementing those suggestions and they all result in the same line having the same out of range problem?

Comment: Use one *or* the other (so use `self.cube[k][j][i]` *or* looping over `i` first), not both.

Comment: I implemented them separately sorry. Thanks for the help though

Comment: Then break this down; use `try:`, `return self.cube[i][j][k]`, `except IndexError:` to catch the exception, and test if `self.cube[i]` works, test if `self.cube[i][j]` works, etc. Test the length of each level to verify you are not missing some elements here, etc.

Comment: @Jack: It seems very likely that this is the error… but there's a very easy way to check. If `i`, `j`, and `k` are all equal, does the error go away? If not you've ruled out this problem as the cause.

Comment: @Martijn Thanks for all of that, I have now got no problems